# custom date format to mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

From a custom utility class, I get the format of a date variable in the following format: `d-m-Y`. My plan is to use `Date('Y-m-d', strtotime($myCustomDate))` but I'm not sure that PHP will return me the right date every time. How can I be sure that my approach is safe?

How can I know that 02-03-2013 will not be transformed as mysql equivalent of 03 February 2013, when I need 02 March 2013.

How do you deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The safest way (other than using timestamps, which is a whole different story), would be to use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, since there can not be the inverse ( ie `YYYY-DD-MM` is not defined), and MySQL understands it well.

You can then use PHP to convert it to any other desired format.

Comment: and YYYY-MM-DD is even sortable

Comment: @hexbot: isn't `Y-m-d`the php equivalent of mysql `YYYY-MM-DD`? my problem is between php converts

Comment: to be safe, once you get it from MySQL convert to timestamp. All PHP functions use timestamps as their source, and you don't have to bother with formatting hassles.

Comment: I need to send it to mysql, not to get it from MySql

Comment: `strtotime` is the key to that, since that will essentially convert your date. See formats available [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) , they are made not to conflict.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always d-m-Y, then you can use a preg_split function to break the date into its component parts and then reformat it using date

```
<?PHP 
  $date = "3-13-2013";
  $date_parts = preg_split("/-/",$date);
  $newDate = Date("Y-m-d",mktime(0, 0, 0, $date_parts[0], $date_parts[1], $date_parts[2]));
?>
```

This will result in $newDate having the value 2013-03-13.